# GData Objective c Client deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, youtube-api, gdata-api

On the [Link](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list?can=1&q=gdata&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) it is mentioned that gdata client for objective c is deprecated. Does anyone know what is the alternative way to upload videos to youtube??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GData library is not deprecated, only the old versions listed on the download page are.

As the summary on the first download says:

> Visit the Source Checkout page and use the svn command shown

Click on the Source tab towards the top of the page and you will find the latest version, which has a lot of changes since the last download that they provide (1.12.0)

Comment: but 1.12.0 is also depreciated there. the only thing not depreciated is the first project and a text file. all others have depreciated word along-with them

Comment: We stopped posting zipped releases because they discouraged developers from keeping an updated source tree.  Developers should check out and periodically update the source tree from the subversion server.

Answer (score 1):

The Link point to the download of the ready-made zips. These zip files are deprecated

The source is updated. Last commit is from August 6: [see the changes](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/list)